# Laravel WSL Docker MYSQL connection issues in terminal while using 'DB_HOST=mysql'

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a issue while developing using Laravel in Windows 10 with WSL & docker since I reinstalled Ubuntu on WSL.

If I run any command that requires DB access in the terminal such as `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }

      +39 vendor frames

  40  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I can fix this error by changing the value of `DB_HOST` in my `.env` file to `127.0.0.1` however this then breaks the application in the browser as this works with the standard `DB_HOST=mysql`. This is getting a little annoying to have to keep changing this value, how can I fix this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you running `php artisan migrate` INSIDE the docker container or outside? It must be run inside and be `DB_HOST=YOUR_DB_CONTAINER_NAME`. Add more info related to the docker compose and how you are executing the commands

Comment: Ive been running it from ubuntu inside WSL as I have always done until this reinstall/update.
Laravel presets all the docker names and details inside the .env and docker file also, it seems to be correct as it works with the browser?

Comment: And what is that "Laravel preset"? Are you using Laravel Sail? Whatever you are using, if you are using Docker, you must run the commands inside the Laravel Docker Container, because the network is only available to it inside (unless you expose all containers to the outside, but that makes not much sense)

Comment: I use docker-compose and the way I get around this is to have my .env file to work from the console and then override the ones I need to in the docker-compose.yml file under the env section of the affected containers.

Answer (score 2):

You can not run artisan commands in your linux terminal since your laravel app is inside a docker container. In order to run any commands related to your app you must access your container first.

First step is to get a list of your containers, you can do that by running in your linux terminal the command `docker ps`.

This will list you all the containers you got running.

Now in order to access a container you need the name of it, you can find if from your `docker-compose.yml` file you got  OR you can use the `container_id`.

In order to access a container you use:

`docker exec -it <container> bash`

or

`docker exec -it <container> sh`

Now you should see in your terminal that you are in a new environment, you are inside the container. Inside there you can run all the artisan commands or composer commands or any command related to your project.

Your `DB_HOST` should stay as `mysql` this is the current IP of the mysql container you have, so don't change that.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Set `<container-name>` name to your mysql container, it work around as an alias name, and you and access the container with `<container-name>` instead of `<container-id>`, even in cli.

Once you set done, it can also alias as IP to container, you can set `DB_HOST` as container name, it will alias to container ip which docker assigned.

### Docker compose

Docker compose will auto prefix container name with folder name and service name.

For example:

```
.
├── ...
└── project
    ├── ...
    └── docker-compose.yml
```

If your service named `mysql`, it will build up container with a container name `project-mysql-1` as default.

**Solve by add `container_name` option.**

Add `container_name` to your mysql service, then you set .env to `DB_HOST=mysql` to work around.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql # Set container name with this
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

### Docker cli

If you are using `docker run`, it won't set container name if you didn't specify, you can only access from the `<container-id>`.

**Solve by use `--name` flag.**

Run up container with command like `docker run mysql --name=mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exactly same problem.

```
Host OS: Windows 11
WSL2: Ubuntu
Docker: Running laravel built with sail
Name of database service on docker-compose file: mysql
DB_HOST: mysql
```

I wasn't able to get both the Host OS and the WSL (ubuntu) getting access to it, but the solution is pretty simple.

You just need to use the PHP that is inside the docker container, and not the php from WSL. In my case PHP is inside the "sail" docker container, to use this specific PHP you simply run:

`$sail php`

example:

`$sail php artisan migrate`

This way you can keep the `DB_HOST = mysql` and get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using Windows 10, WSL2, Docker (PHP-FPM, MySQL), Laravel**

Imagine your "docker-compose.yml" file in your Laravel installation:
(this is not a full version of this file)

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    php_fpm:
        image: php:8.1-fpm
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql:8.0.34
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel_test
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

Then in my ".env" file from Laravel I specified the "DB_HOST=mysqldb".
("mysqldb" is the service name from my "docker-compose.yml" file)

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysqldb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Then I open my PHPStorm terminal and I run:
("php_fpm" is the service name from my "docker-compose.yml" file)

```
docker-compose exec php_fpm php artisan migrate
```